# Only count variable is being updated in for loop while other variables are not

Tags: c++

I'm working on a mortgage calculator and I'm able to get the for loop to work, but it is only updating the (count) variable and not the other variables (interest, principal, balance). I attempted to nest a while loop, but that did not work. I want the for loop to keep updating the other variables till the count variable gets to the calculated loan term.
Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Main program
int main()
{

int loanAmount,
    term,
    numOfYears,
    count;

double yearlyRate,
    monthlyPay,
    balance,
    monthlyRate,
    totalPay,
    interest,
    principal;

char answer;

    do
    {
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);

        // User input
        cout << "Enter loan amount: ";
        cin >> loanAmount;
        while (loanAmount < 0)
                    {
                        cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number. Enter the loan amount: ";
                        cin >> loanAmount;
                    }

        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of years for the loan: ";
        cin >> numOfYears;
        while (numOfYears < 0)
                    {
                        cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number. Enter the number of years: ";
                        cin >> numOfYears;
                    }

        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "Enter yearly interest rate: ";
        cin >> yearlyRate;
        while (yearlyRate < 0)
                    {
                        cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a positive number. Enter the yearly rate: ";
                        cin >> yearlyRate;
                    }

        // Output of user input
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "Loan Amount: " << loanAmount << endl;
        cout << "Number of Years: " << numOfYears << endl;

        cout << "Interest Rate: " << yearlyRate << "%" << endl;
        yearlyRate = yearlyRate / 100;      // convert interest rate percent to decimal

        monthlyRate = yearlyRate / 12;      // calculate monthly interest rate

        // Calculate and display monthly payment and total payment of loan
        monthlyPay = loanAmount * monthlyRate / (1 - (pow(1 / (1 + monthlyRate), numOfYears * 12)));

        totalPay = monthlyPay * term;

        cout << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "Monthly Payment: " << monthlyPay << endl;      // display first monthly payment
        cout << "Total Payment: " << totalPay << endl;          // display total loan balance paid after interest is applied
        cout << "\n" << endl;

        cout << "Payment #\tInterest\tPrincipal\tBalance\t\n";
        cout << "\n" << endl;
        for (int count = 1; count <= numOfYears * 12; count++)
        {
            interest = monthlyRate * loanAmount;
            principal = monthlyPay - interest;
            balance = loanAmount - principal;
            cout << count << "\t\t" << interest << "\t\t" << principal << "\t\t" << balance << endl;
        }
        

        cout << "\nWould you like to run the program again? (Y/N): \n";
        cin >> answer;
    } while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');     // restarts loop if user inputs Y or N(uppercase or lowercase)
        if (answer != 'Y' || answer != 'y')
        {
            cout << "\n\nEnd Program.\n";       // ends loop if answer is not Y or y
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since none of `loanAmount`, `monthlyRate` or `monthlyPay` values change inside the loop, you keep making the same computations that produce the same numbers, over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation loop is not setup, nor run, correctly.

- Before the loop `balance` should be set to the initial loan amount.
- The interest should be based on the current balance, not the loan amount.
- the balance should be adjusted to reduce by principle on each iteration

It should look like this:

```
balance = loanAmount;
for (int count = 1; count <= numOfYears * 12; count++)
{
    interest = monthlyRate * balance;
    principal = monthlyPay - interest;
    balance -= principal;
    cout << count << "\t\t" << interest << "\t\t" << principal << "\t\t" << balance << endl;
}
```

Making this adjustment, a 100k 10 year fixed rate 5% loan comes out to:

```
Payment #       Interest        Principal       Balance


1               416.67          643.99          99356.01
2               413.98          646.67          98709.34
3               411.29          649.37          98059.97
4               408.58          652.07          97407.90
5               405.87          654.79          96753.11
6               403.14          657.52          96095.60
7               400.40          660.26          95435.34
8               397.65          663.01          94772.33
9               394.88          665.77          94106.56
10              392.11          668.54          93438.02
11              389.33          671.33          92766.69
12              386.53          674.13          92092.56
13              383.72          676.94          91415.62
14              380.90          679.76          90735.87
15              378.07          682.59          90053.28
16              375.22          685.43          89367.84
17              372.37          688.29          88679.55
18              369.50          691.16          87988.40
19              366.62          694.04          87294.36
20              363.73          696.93          86597.43
21              360.82          699.83          85897.60
22              357.91          702.75          85194.85
23              354.98          705.68          84489.17
24              352.04          708.62          83780.56
25              349.09          711.57          83068.99
26              346.12          714.53          82354.45
27              343.14          717.51          81636.94
28              340.15          720.50          80916.44
29              337.15          723.50          80192.94
30              334.14          726.52          79466.42
31              331.11          729.55          78736.87
32              328.07          732.58          78004.29
33              325.02          735.64          77268.65
34              321.95          738.70          76529.95
35              318.87          741.78          75788.17
36              315.78          744.87          75043.30
37              312.68          747.97          74295.32
38              309.56          751.09          73544.23
39              306.43          754.22          72790.01
40              303.29          757.36          72032.65
41              300.14          760.52          71272.13
42              296.97          763.69          70508.44
43              293.79          766.87          69741.57
44              290.59          770.07          68971.51
45              287.38          773.27          68198.23
46              284.16          776.50          67421.74
47              280.92          779.73          66642.00
48              277.68          782.98          65859.02
49              274.41          786.24          65072.78
50              271.14          789.52          64283.26
51              267.85          792.81          63490.46
52              264.54          796.11          62694.34
53              261.23          799.43          61894.91
54              257.90          802.76          61092.16
55              254.55          806.10          60286.05
56              251.19          809.46          59476.59
57              247.82          812.84          58663.75
58              244.43          816.22          57847.53
59              241.03          819.62          57027.90
60              237.62          823.04          56204.87
61              234.19          826.47          55378.40
62              230.74          829.91          54548.49
63              227.29          833.37          53715.12
64              223.81          836.84          52878.27
65              220.33          840.33          52037.94
66              216.82          843.83          51194.11
67              213.31          847.35          50346.77
68              209.78          850.88          49495.89
69              206.23          854.42          48641.47
70              202.67          857.98          47783.49
71              199.10          861.56          46921.93
72              195.51          865.15          46056.78
73              191.90          868.75          45188.03
74              188.28          872.37          44315.66
75              184.65          876.01          43439.65
76              181.00          879.66          42560.00
77              177.33          883.32          41676.67
78              173.65          887.00          40789.67
79              169.96          890.70          39898.97
80              166.25          894.41          39004.56
81              162.52          898.14          38106.43
82              158.78          901.88          37204.55
83              155.02          905.64          36298.91
84              151.25          909.41          35389.50
85              147.46          913.20          34476.30
86              143.65          917.00          33559.30
87              139.83          920.82          32638.48
88              135.99          924.66          31713.81
89              132.14          928.51          30785.30
90              128.27          932.38          29852.92
91              124.39          936.27          28916.65
92              120.49          940.17          27976.48
93              116.57          944.09          27032.39
94              112.63          948.02          26084.37
95              108.68          951.97          25132.40
96              104.72          955.94          24176.47
97              100.74          959.92          23216.55
98              96.74           963.92          22252.63
99              92.72           967.94          21284.69
100             88.69           971.97          20312.72
101             84.64           976.02          19336.70
102             80.57           980.09          18356.62
103             76.49           984.17          17372.45
104             72.39           988.27          16384.18
105             68.27           992.39          15391.79
106             64.13           996.52          14395.27
107             59.98           1000.67         13394.59
108             55.81           1004.84         12389.75
109             51.62           1009.03         11380.72
110             47.42           1013.24         10367.48
111             43.20           1017.46         9350.02
112             38.96           1021.70         8328.33
113             34.70           1025.95         7302.37
114             30.43           1030.23         6272.15
115             26.13           1034.52         5237.62
116             21.82           1038.83         4198.79
117             17.49           1043.16         3155.63
118             13.15           1047.51         2108.13
119             8.78            1051.87         1056.25
120             4.40            1056.25         -0.00
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, and breaking down solution for me. That resolved the issue.